# Dokku refusing deployment on second app

Tags: git, dokku

I have made two dokku apps in Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure using `dokku apps:create appname`

```
$dokku apps
=====> My Apps
api
frontend
```

I can successfully deploy to the first one, but not to the other:

`git push dokku@myserver.com:api` suceeds, but

`git push dokku@myserver.com:frontend` fails with

```
fatal: 'frontend' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by using sshcommand to add users, rather than manually manipulating the `authorized_keys` file, as specified in [this](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1896) issue.